# Is it possible to use MathJax in DisQus?

Tags: disqus, mathjax

I followed the instructions [here](http://checkmyworking.com/2012/01/how-to-get-beautifully-typeset-maths-on-your-blog/#disqus), however, it didn't take any effect.

Do you know some way to allow commenters to use MathJax in their DisQus comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very [same link](http://checkmyworking.com/2012/01/how-to-get-beautifully-typeset-maths-on-your-blog/#disqus) gives you the answer: Disqus is now using an iframe, so the answer is no.

For [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) reasons, browsers will not allow you to inject a third party javascript (i.e. MathJax) into the Disqus iframe.

Comment: Is there any other comments module like Disqus supported MathJax in GitHub pages?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @HyperGroups [IntenseDebate might work](http://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-community-update/), but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @ChongxuRen You may use [Staticman](https://staticman.net/), which creates pull requests to the Git repo, so as to allow Markdown (i.e. MathJax/KaTeX) rendering in comments.  You may view [my minimal example](https://vincenttam.gitlab.io/test-hugo-staticman/posts/test-staticman/) on GitLab Pages, its [source code](https://gitlab.com/VincentTam/test-hugo-staticman), as well as the [source code](https://github.com/VincentTam/staticman/tree/deploy) for [my Staticman API instance](http://staticman3.herokuapp.com/) to see how they work.